# When printing website (react component), how to set width for react-bootstrap breakpoints for layout?

Tags: reactjs, printing, react-bootstrap, responsiveness

We have a react application and would like users to be able to easily and cleanly print the various pages on the website. Our application uses react-bootstrap grid to handle responsiveness. Here is a snippet of one of our pages, which includes two tables. These tables are side-by-side in the top image (based on both the `xl` and `lg` breakpoints, which use two columns with size 6), and stacked in the bottom image (based on the `md` breakpoint, with size = 12).

**First Image**
[image]

**Second Image**
[image]

When I hit CMD + P to launch the print window, I receive the following for this part of the page with the 2 tables:

[image]

The print window always shows the two tables stacked, regardless of the current width of my browser. However, for printing, I would prefer for the two tables to be side-by-side, not stacked.

Is it possible to control / change the "width" of the page as perceived by the printer? I assume that currently the print functionality is simply treating the page as some width that falls into the `md` breakpoint, however it would be great for the page to use the `lg` or (preferred) `xl` breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have something like this as your markup:

```
<div class="row row-of-tables">
    <div class="col col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">Table 1</div>
    <div class="col col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">Table 2</div>
</div>
```

When printing, the below code will make the cols take up `max-width` of `50%` just like what `col-lg-6` or `col-xl-6` does

```
@media print {
    .row.row-of-tables > .col {
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}
```